# Refactor Class to Hook element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to translate a Class component to a Hook component, but struggling to translate a few things:

```
  sceneSetup = () => {
    const width = this.el.clientWidth;
    const height = this.el.clientHeight;
    this.el.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
  };
```

**1) How would `this.el?` this be translated into a hook component?**

---

Also in my render method i return this:

```
  render() {
    return(
        <div ref={ref => (this.el = ref)} />
    ) 
  }
```

**2) How does the div translate into a hook?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would this.el? this be translated into a hook component?

Use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.

> 2) How does the div translate into a hook?

Simply return `div` using `el` ref.

```
function Scene() {
  const el = useRef(null);

  return <div ref={el} /> // init el ref
}
```

Alternatively, you may also use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) for purpose of *measuring the node dimensions*.

```
function Scene() {
  const [rect, setRect] = useState(null);

  const callbackRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={callbackRef} /> // use callback ref
}
```